# How do I find / buy "pastry bars"?

Tags: baking

In Moderist cuisine, they repeatedly refer to "pastry bars" for a number of techniques. However, when I try to search / find these things on the internet, my search engine results are hundreds of thousands of snack bars and other Kellog's "boxed products".

I've tried "baking bars", "baking weights" and a number of other variations.

Is there another name for these things that will help me find them?

Here's an image showing "baking bars" on a silicone mat to create a gel:

[image: Here are "baking bars" on top of a silicon mat]

Comment: That looks a lot like the table/tools they use to make hard candy

Comment: I bet they cost considerably more if you buy them from a confectionery tools provider, rather than your local metal works.

Comment: @Strawberry and presumably have fewer stray metal burrs / shavings in them too... ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Pastry bars metal" seems to work. The results I got were for "caramel ruler bars" or "ganache ruler bars". Other terms are "confectionery rulers" which gave me a [forum](https://cheftalk.com/threads/confectionery-rulers.72198/) that recommended getting them cut for you at a metal shop from stainless steel at whatever lengths you want for less than buying purpose made ones.

That said, I'm not sure that's actually what you're looking for. These seem to be bars for rolling out dough or fondant to a specific thickness, not designed to be used for shaping things the way your photo implies.

The term that I found that more closely resembles what you're looking for is "confectionery frames".

Comment: You are spot on (and beat me by a minute). The keyword is “rulers” - caramel, ganache, confectionery, depending on the seller - and the thicker ones are indeed also used for pouring. Steel is better than aluminum, due to the weight.

Answer (score 5):

These look like simple aluminum profiles (in this case, hollow squares). Find someone selling aluminum bars/pipes etc by the foot/meter (maybe a DIY shop). Saw them to the desired size yourself and sandpaper the saw cuts (or ask a handy acquaintance).

Comment: Many bakers / cooks do. (Stainless) steel is a sturdy and heavier alternative and sometimes preferred because less likely to slip.

Comment: There's limited opportunities to combine angle grinders and cooking, and this is one of them! :)

Comment: Just make sure that the metal is not coated with something unhealthy.

Comment: @GdD It's not worth getting the angle grinder out for Al (which clogs it anyway).  But stainless steel wouldn't cut in a reasonable time with a hacksaw.

Comment: I would probably go for stainless in this application myself anyway, @ChrisH, this is just one more reason for it.

Comment: Agreed with @GdD - shop stock bars will often have some type of machine oil, etc, coated on them.  This is definitely not food grade stuff.  Hollow bars will be harder to clean than solid, but any shop stock should probably have a good cleaning with something like Spray-9 followed by hot soapy water and then high-concentration rubbing alcohol and a rinse before touching food.